# How to count row based on 2 sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets named A & B.

A has 3 columns (ID, Date, Name) and B has 3 columns (ID, Status, Level). A.ID and B.ID are same.

I want to count the status(two information “Done” or “Not Done”) based on A.Date range.

My Formula is:
`=COUNTIFS(A!A2:A1048576,B!A2:A1048576,A!G2:G1048576,">=01-01-2020",A!G2:G1048576,"<=30-06-2020", B!B2:B1048576, “Done”)`

But every time it shows 1. By manual filter it shows 12.

Comment: Please read HELP for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question to provide more information so as to be able to reproduce your problem. Or post a new question if this one has been closed

Comment: While you should do what @RonRosenfeld asked you to do, you should also not put these criteria in COUNTIFS: `A!A2:A1048576,B!A2:A1048576,`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a column (i.e. `F`) with formula: `=A2=B!A2`, and doing:

I created a 'sample' with only 17 rows, and i use ';' a separator in formula's ()

```
=COUNTIFS(B!B2:B17;"=Done";A!B2:B17;"<=01-08-2020";A!B2:B17;">=01-02-2020";F2:F17;"=TRUE")
```

CriteriaRange1: B!B2:B17
Criteria1     : "=Done"

Only count values that are "Done"

CriteriaRange2: A!B2:B17
Criteria2     : "<=01-08-2020"

Only count when date is (on or )before 1 August

CriteriaRange3: A!B2:B17
Criteria3     : ">=01-02-2020"

Only count when date is (on or )after 1 Februari

CriteriaRange4: A!F2:F17
Criteria4     : "=TRUE"

The formula in F checks if A!A2 is equal to B!A2 (for all rows)

I do hope there is an easier way to do the `Criteria4`